# Make an array from a file

Tags: sql, arrays, linux, bash

Well, im using bash script, now i got an output in a file called "differ2", 
the file contains some lines such that:

```
table3 ('13','20', '50');
table4 ('13','20', '50','60','70');
table5 ('13','20');
```

I need make an array who takes the name of the tables and another to take the values, i want to put this arrays in file for make an insert like this:

```
INSERT INTO $array_table
VALUES ($array_values);

INSERT INTO $array_table
VALUES ($array_values);
```

Comment: What did you try for yourself? Post your research efforts

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
l34rn3r@l34rn3r-Aspire-E5-571 /tmp $ cat input.txt 
table3 ('13','20', '50');
table4 ('13','20', '50','60','70');
table5 ('13','20');
l34rn3r@l34rn3r-Aspire-E5-571 /tmp $ awk '{ print "insert into "$1" values ";$1=""; print$0}' input.txt 
insert into table3 values 
 ('13','20', '50');
insert into table4 values 
 ('13','20', '50','60','70');
insert into table5 values 
 ('13','20');
```